# estimating fixed-effects and interactions

Tags: mixed-model, inference

I have read and understood the use of mixed-effect models for repeated measures. I would like help correctly specifying the type of model for my experiment. I recruited 3 types of subjects to listen to stimuli that have 4 variations over 8 different tests and score an opinion. The stimuli are the same for each test.

I believe that:

- random effect: stimuli (repeated)
- fixed effects: type_subjects, variations;

I guess the model should become:

```
model1 = lmer(Score ~ type_subject + (1|stimulus), database)
model2 = lmer(Score ~ variation + (1|stimulus), database)
```

or (for interaction)

```
model_interaction = lmer(Score ~ type_subject*variation + (1|stimulus), database)
```

Is this correct?

How do I obtain inference for these model effects?

Comment: The designation of fixed vs random effect is not primarily based on the number of experimental levels but rather a. what is the primary exposure of interest and b. which factor requires the most precise estimation. What factor in this experiment is merely a blocking a factor and what is a treatment or quasitreatment?

Comment: Also see the help file `?lme` for examples of performing inference.

Comment: could you explain your experiment design a little clearer? I am not certain if you have 1 subject taking multiple tests. Are they listening to the same stimulus multiple times?